# Determine whether a wall intersection is mitred or butted

Tags: c#, revit-api

Using the Revit API how can I determine if the wall intersection(join) type is a mitered join or a butt join.

Where it is a butt-join, how can I determine which wall is the butted-up one?

Can I programmatically change the intersection type and how might I do this using the Revit API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the wall object, there is a LocationCurve property.
On the LocationCurve object, you will find two relevant properties:

- ElementsAtJoin[ int end ]:  Determine the elements joining at the given end.
- JoinType [ int end ]:  Determine the join type (i.e. Mitred, Butt, etc)

the JoinType is changeable.